# Does object have attribute

Tags: c#, object, attributes, protobuf-net

Given the class:

```
[ProtoContract]
[Serializable]
public class TestClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

And the method:

```
public static void Set(object objectToCache)
{

}
```

Is it possible to check if `objectToCache` has the attribute `ProtoContract`?

Comment: `objectToCache.GetType().GetCustomAttributes()` or a variation thereof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use following code:

```
public static void Set(object objectToCache)
{
    Console.WriteLine(objectToCache.GetType().IsDefined(typeof(MyAttribute), true));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
var attributes = TestClass.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ProtoContract), true);
if(attributes.Length < 1)
    return; //we don't have the attribute
var attribute = attributes[0] as ProtoContract;
if(attribute != null)
{
   //access the attribute as needed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `GetCustomAttributes` which will return a collection of attributes the given object has. Then check if any are of your desired type

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Set(new TestClass());
}

public static void Set(object objectToCache)
{
    var result = objectToCache.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(false)
                                        .Any(att => att is ProtoContractAttribute);

    // Or other overload:
    var result2 = objectToCache.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ProtoContractAttribute), false).Any();
    // result - true   
 }
```

---

Reading more about `IsDefined` as Александр Лысенко suggested it does seem to be what you are looking for:

> Returns true if one or more instances of attributeType or any of its derived types is applied to this member; otherwise, false.